# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException seems to be counting wrong array

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that I just can't resolve.

In a nutshell, it is a children's app for learning names of letters, numbers, and seven other categories of common objects. It displays an image of the object/character/numeral with the name in text underneath, and corresponding audio of the name when the object is tapped.

The user can select English or Arabic.

Everything works with the exception of the Arabic letters, with the exception being thrown for the string array of the letters in Arabic text.

Here's an example of a small category that works:

```
        if (categoryNumber == 2) {
        //Colors
        Resources resources = getResources();
        items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.colors);
        if (language == 0) {            
            if (letter == 0) {
                items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.colors);
            }
            if (letter == 1) {
                items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.colors_caps);
                }
            if (letter == 2) {
                items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.colors_mixed);
            } 
        } else if (language == 1 ) {
            items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.colors_arabic);
        }
```

and the first string array involved as an example:

```
    <string-array name="colors">
    <item>red</item>
    <item>yellow</item>
    <item>blue</item>
    <item>green</item>
    <item>pink</item>
    <item>orange</item>
    <item>black</item>
    <item>white</item>
    <item>brown</item>
    <item>purple</item>
    <item>gold</item>
    <item>silver</item>
</string-array>
```

and its corresponding arabic array:

```
    <string-array name="colors_arabic">
    <!-- red -->
    <item>أحمر</item>
    <!-- yellow -->
    <item>أصفر</item>
    <!-- blue -->
    <item>أزرق</item>
    <!-- green -->
    <item>أخضر</item>
    <!-- pink -->
    <item>وردي</item>
    <!-- orange -->
    <item>البرتقالي</item>
    <!-- black -->
    <item>أسود</item>
    <!-- white -->
    <item>أبيض</item>
    <!-- brown -->
    <item>بني</item>
    <!-- purple -->
    <item>بنفسجي</item>
    <!-- gold -->
    <item>ذهبي</item>
    <!-- silver -->
    <item>فضي</item>
</string-array>
```

However, when it comes to the 'letters' category there is an important difference - there are 28 letters in the Arabic alphabet vs. 26 in English.

So for the code for the 'letters' category:

```
        if (categoryNumber == 3) {
        //Letters
        Resources resources = getResources();
        if(language == 0) {
            if (letter == 0) {
                items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.letters);
                }
            if (letter == 1) {
                items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.letters_caps);
                }
            if (letter == 2) {
                items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.letters_mixed);
                }               
        } else if (language == 1) {
            items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.letters_arabic);
        }
```

and the corresponding arabic array:

```
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="letters_arabic">
    <!-- arabicletterone  -->
    <item>أ</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwo -->
    <item>ب</item>
    <!-- arabicletterthree -->
    <item>ت</item>
    <!-- arabicletterfour -->
    <item>ث</item>
    <!-- arabicletterfive -->
    <item>ج</item>
    <!-- arabiclettersix -->
    <item>ح</item>
    <!-- arabicletterseven -->
    <item>خ</item>
    <!-- arabiclettereight -->
    <item>د</item>
    <!-- arabicletternine -->
    <item>ذ</item>
    <!-- arabicletterten -->
    <item>ر</item>
    <!-- arabiclettereleven -->
    <item>ز</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwelve -->
    <item>س</item>
    <!-- arabicletterthirteen -->
    <item>ش</item>
    <!-- arabicletterfourteen -->
    <item>ص</item>
    <!-- arabicletterfifteen -->
    <item>ض</item>
    <!-- arabiclettersixteen -->
    <item>ط</item>
    <!-- arabicletterseventeen -->
    <item>ظ</item>
    <!-- arabiclettereighteen -->
    <item>ع</item>
    <!-- arabicletternineteen -->
    <item>غ</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwenty -->
    <item>ف</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentyone -->
    <item>ق</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentytwo -->
    <item>ك</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentythree -->
    <item>ل</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentyfour -->
    <item>م</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentyfive -->
    <item>ن</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentysix -->
    <item>ه</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentyseven -->
    <item>و</item>
    <!-- arabiclettertwentyeight -->
    <item>ي</item>
</string-array>
```

and the error I get is:

09-01 20:14:07.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.allababiditech.academics/com.allababiditech.academics.LevelOneActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=28

When I substitute a completely different array of 28 items using English characters I get the same exception.

If I substitute the english letters text array the Arabic images and audio work fine (at least the first 26).

If I use the english text array and add two duplicate English characters to it, I get the same exception only now the length and index are off by two more.

If I use as a substitute any of the other categories' text arrays in English or Arabic, the Arabic images and audio work for the number of text items as long as the array has 26 or less text items in it. (The 'letters' is the longest array of all the categories.)

I would think that it doesn't matter that there are more Arabic than English letters, since everything is based on the number of items in the string array such that items.length would be 28 rather than 26.

I've been beating my head against the monitor all day and I'm hoping someone doesn't mind taking a peek and pointing out the really simple, obvious mistake that I'm just not seeing. Thanks so much.

EDIT:  Sorry, didn't put this in because it's pretty simple and works with everything else.
in onCreate:

```
itemNumber = 0; ...
categoryItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
categoryItem.setText(items[itemNumber]);
```

then of course later this iterates as the child advances from one object to the next.

09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.allababiditech.academics/com.allababiditech.academics.LevelOneActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=28
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=28
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at com.allababiditech.academics.LevelOneActivity.onCreate(LevelOneActivity.java:1454)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
09-01 22:18:09.586: E/AndroidRuntime(9524):     ... 11 more

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and your LevelOneActivity?

Comment: Post the code block where you are accessing the Arabic letters array. You should never reach "index=28" as the max/highest index is 27 (i.e., total 28 letters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest existing index for an array with 28 items is 27 - because array indices starts with 0 in Java (and most other programming languages). It seems that you start counting from 1 to 28 and that causes the exception.

Comment: Yes, except I explicitly start at 0, and it works for the eight other categories in English and Arabic, plus this category in English. That's exactly what I'm hung up on... why is it behaving differently?

Comment: Soooo, I totally forgot about my array of Arabic numerals that displayed which number of items the child was on, and it only went to 26 (we weren't originally to have an Arabic option). Though I understand index order vs. length, it was your reference to counting that restarted my malfunctioning brain cell. Thanks!